# How to create AWS SQS FIFO queue in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I am new to **AWS SQS**.

I have used this code to create the **AWS SQS Standard queue**.

```
sqs = Aws::SQS::Client.new
queue = sqs.create_queue(queue_name: "myqueue")
puts "INFO - Queue URL: #{queue.queue_url}"
```

But I am not sure how to create a **FIFO queue**.

Anyone can help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIFO queue name **must end with** `.fifo`. Also you have attributes in [create_queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v2/api/Aws/SQS/Client.html#create_queue-instance_method).

Thus, I think the following should work:

```
queue = sqs.create_queue(
     queue_name: "myqueue.fifo",
     attributes: {"FifoQueue" => "true"})
```

Comment: it works but attributes: {"FifoQueue" => "true"} is more correct I think.